# Ionic 2 build release 404 error

Tags: build, ionic2

I build an ionic 2 app. When I build an android debug version with `ionic build android --prod` the app works like a charm. But when I build the same unchanged app with `ionic build android --prod --release` and I sign the app and zip align it and open the app nothing works and all request give a 404 error. Anyone suggestions?

I installed the whitelist plugin and also set the meta security in the index and in the config.xml the `<allow tags`

Comment: Have you seen this. See more: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-build-production-apps-today/73219/2

Comment: That's not the problem tried different build ways

Comment: Can you send the snippet of the whole error?

Comment: Problem is that you can't debug a release version but i added an image from an external accepted domain and in the debug version the image loads and in the release version it does'nt

Comment: Do you get any java or javascript errors? I once had a similar problem. In my case the error was an invalid or misconfigured certificate on the server which made all my API calls fail silently.

Comment: The api call's also won't work but an image must be loaded and has nothing to do with an certificate, before i had that problem also with the debug version but after install the whitelist cordova plugin it works on the debug version

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the SSL certificate. The hoster forgot to add the Intermediate Certificate. On IOS this is no problem but on android it is.